# Getting images to link to website

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

I put this in the following file: index.html

```
<ul class="youtube">
    <li class="gamerscafe"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClExmFafx9vTZxDHPwg74Pg"></a></li>
    <li class="destiny"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyrifIvvkvGj1c-ltnbop4A"></a></li>
    <li class="halo"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCjdkHFov_Tqb9mzrEXStrog"></a></li>
    <li class="assassins"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSFscOh0tN1hsz-7UMIVYkQ"></a></li>
    <li class="gearsofwar"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC26Tt6oTOS4UpdGzAOVMZKA"></a></li>
    <li class="armyoftwo"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqvhFvrTYsv3VGg9j9elNtA"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And i put this in the style.css sheet...

```
ul.youtube
{
width: 650px;
margin: 0px auto 0;
height: 10px;
}

ul.youtube li{
float: left;
background: url(../images/youtube.png) left top no-repeat;
position: relative;
height: 20px;
margin-right: 70px;
}

ul.youtube li a{
display: block;
width: 18px;
height: 20px;
}
```

However when i hover over the images the link doesn't work is there something i am missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `a` anchors do not include any text/elements to be clicked on.

You need to insert something inside your `a` tags, for example images:

```
<a href="http://URL/TO/DESTINATION">
    <img src="http://URL/TO/IMAGE.png" />
</a>
```

Or, if you just want so span a clickable area, define some element with dimensions inside

```
<a href="http://URL/TO/DESTINATION">
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 300px;"></div>
</a>
```

But the main problem is, that your anchors have no content you could click on.

EDIT: I suppose you could edit the dimensions of the `a` directly as well instead of the div. The `a` would need a `display: block;` or `display:inline-block` for that though

Comment: Greetings; Thanks for the reply, where abouts do i set the anchors ? sorry new to all this....

Comment: More elegant would be setting the dimensions of the A directly, instead of filling it with a div. I edited that

Answer (score 1):

Like Felk said.

You have your `<a>` tag but it doesn't have anything inside.

In order to make the images links you would have to put them inside the `<a>` tag; like so.

```
<li class="gamerscafe"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UClExmFafx9vTZxDHPwg74Pg"><img src=""></img></a></li>
                                                                                                   //^ image code here
```

Comment: He's got a background image in CSS that I assume shows a youtube image

Comment: That is correct, the image is in the CSS....  Here is the link for the site: http://gamerscafe.net/

Comment: I visited your site and used chrome inspect element to see how things are rendered. Basically your a tag is rendered too small. If you increase its size i.e. ul.youtube li a { width: 140px; height: 200px; }, you should get the link on hover. Btw if you apply your background image on the a tag, you would've picked this up straight away because with 18x20 size the image won't be displayed fully to start with.

Comment: Thanks soo much everyone for the help the links are working, however now it is all the same image, instead of being different images for different games... :(

Comment: Thanks to everyone that helped, i have fixed all the image and the site is now working..... Yeaaaaa..

Answer (score 0):

If you move your background image styling into the a tag it should work, like this:

```
ul.youtube li a{
    display: block;
    background: url(http://gamerscafe.net/images/youtube.png) left top no-repeat;
    width: 140px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Then you can apply the positioning this way:

```
ul.youtube li.destiny a {
    background-position: -310px 0px;
}
```

And if you need hover effect:

```
ul.youtube li.destiny a:hover {
    /*style for hover*/
}
```

I have put your site into jsfiddle. Please take a look here for a working version:
https://jsfiddle.net/4vdr8dLf/